# base fee exceeds gas limit , error when deploying using encoded constructor

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, nodejs

I have following small simple contract

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract MyContract {

    uint256 public  totalSupply ; 
    mapping( address => uint256) public  balances ;
    address public owner;

    constructor(address _wallet) public payable {
        totalSupply = 6;
        owner = _wallet;
    }

    function () external payable{
        buyToken();
    }

    function buyToken() public payable {
        require(totalSupply >= (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2);
        balances[msg.sender] += (msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;
        totalSupply -=(msg.value/1000000000000000000)*2;

    }
    function getTotalSupply()public view returns  (uint256 ){
        return totalSupply;
    }
       function setTotalSupply(uint256 newSupply) public {
        require(msg.sender==owner);
        totalSupply = newSupply;

    }

}
```

I want to deploy above contract using its abi, bin(extracted from json file generated by solc compiler version 0.4.24)  and encoded constructor parameters. **it gives following error;**

```
 base fee exceeds gas limit
```

**here is my code:**

```
async function dep(0) {
var params;
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(myAbi[0]);

      if(constructorParams[0]=='') {
          params = '0x' + myBin[0]
      } else {
          params = '0x' + myBin[0]+constructorParams[0]
      }


        try {
        await web3.eth.sendTransaction(
            {from:account1,
            data: params
                }, function(err, receipt) {console.log(receipt)});
        } catch (error) {
        console.log(" ERROR !", error); 
        }
}
```

**Some values which may be required for your queries;**

I am using Nodejs, Javascript, and Ganache GUI with gaslimit : 100000000, Gas price : 20000000000.
Here is some values

```
constructorParams[0] :  0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
myAbi[0] : [
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'totalSupply',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0x18160ddd'
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'balances',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0x27e235e3'
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'owner',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0x8da5cb5b'
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'buyToken',
    outputs: [],
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0xa4821719'
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getTotalSupply',
    outputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0xc4e41b22'
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    name: 'setTotalSupply',
    outputs: [],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'nonpayable',
    type: 'function',
    signature: '0xf7ea7a3d'
  },
  {
    inputs: [ [Object] ],
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'constructor',
    constant: undefined
  },
  {
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'fallback',
    constant: undefined
  }
]

myBin: 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
```

Comment: Note that in your code, the `if(constructorParams[0]=='')` / `else` part is redundant. You can simply do `const params = '0x' + myBin[0]+constructorParams[0];`, or even get rid of this variable and do `data: '0x' + myBin[0]+constructorParams[0];`.

Comment: That said, check the size of your bin file. It cannot exceed 48K (representing a binary contract-size of 24k). Oh wait, I see it here at the bottom of your question, so forget it (just keep this restriction in mind for future reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to deploy your contract via the following:

```
async function send(web3, privateKey, params)
    const options = {
        data: params,
        gas: 2000000,
    };
    const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey);
    const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
    console.log(receipt.contractAddress);
}
```

It's deployed at `0xc40757e5E9FAaa9D3c7eEAd99d123F8042629B49` on Ropsten, in case you're interested.